# Removing a specific list from an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have this list

```
list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 0]]
```

I want to take 2 integers

```
row = 2 and column = 1
```

Combine them

```
thing = (str(row) + str(", ") + str(column))
```

then I want to remove the list

```
[2, 1]
```

from the array. How would I do this?

EDIT:  The language is ***Python***

Comment: I don't get the combine part, do you still need help with that? Removing the list from the larger list is just `list.remove([2, 1])`.

Comment: @MalcolmMoss If the language is Python then the arrays is list :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't name your list `list`. It will overwrite the builtin function `list()` and potentially mess with your code later.

Secondly, finding and removing elements in a list is done like

```
data.remove(value)
```

or in your case

```
data.remove([2, 1])
```

Specifically, where you are looking for an entry `[row, column]`, you would do

```
data.remove([row, column])
```

where `row` and `column` are your two variables.

It may be a bit confusing to name them `row` and `column`, though. because your data could be interpreted as a matrix/2D array, where "row" and "column" have a different meaning.